# How to redirect a single file without affecting the rest of the domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

this is my first post to StackOverFlow so let me know if I do anything wrong.

I am working on websites for a handful of restaurants owned by a single guy. Each restaurant is slightly different with their menu, and they are all, obviously, different locations.

I want to make it so when someone goes to `www.website.com`, it redirects them to another website at `restaurants.website.com`. That website will have a link to the 'actual' website which will be at `www.website.com/home/`

To get the website to exist at /home/, I moved the entire site (wordpress) from the root folder to a folder titled 'home'

I put an `index.php` in the root folder with some redirect code in it to send any visitors to `www.website.com` to `restaurants.website.com` instead.

However, when I set up that redirect, anyone going to `www.website.com/home/` still gets redirected to `restaurants.website.com`.

I think maybe the answer is in an `.htaccess` file, but I really do not know, and I have exhausted all options.

Thank you so much for your help ahead of time, anyone willing.

Comment: you need to provide some code, ie your .htaccess file

Comment: Sorry, my htaccess file is really not going to help, as it is blank. I was doing the redirect in index.php and it just contains this:

<?php header('location: http://restaurants.toscopizza.com/'); exit;

Answer (score 0):

put this in your .htaccess in your root

```
Redirect / http://restaurants.toscopizza.com/
```

Comment: Alright, I will give it a try. Do I still need an index.php in the root? will it need anything in it?

This won't redirect the subfolders in root?

Comment: I tried it, and for some reason, it is still redirecting the subdirectories too. 

when I go to www.website.com/home/ it still redirects to restaurants.website.com

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but this is the contents of the .htaccess file inside the /home/ folder -- come to think of it, do I still need that there? 

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /home/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /home/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: Try it like this: have a root folder containing an index.php with `header('location: http://restaurants.toscopizza.com/');`                                    and your subdirectory called home, in here have your index.php with your actual homepage.                                                                  If this doesn't work try deleting parts of your existing .htaccess that may cause the problem.

Comment: there is nothing else in my .htaccess file. And the index.php in the home folder already exists as it is a wordpress site.